# Flutter/Dart: When is the keyword this used?

Tags: flutter, dart, this, keyword

I know how to use the keyword this, but I am not sure if there are situations where it has to be avoided for some reasons. Example from [dart.dev, chapter constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors):

```
class Point {
  double x, y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);

  // Named constructor
  Point.origin() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
  }
}
```

Why don't they write

```
this.x = 0;
```

instead of

```
x = 0;
```

?

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-this-when-not-needed-to-avoid-shadowing

Answer (score 4):

In this case you can write `this.x` as well, it's just a matter of style.

Generally, when there's no ambiguity, it's recommended to skip `this` as it's invoked implicitly.